# XUnit run by Jenkins fails with missing dependency (wrong version) for XUnit.extensions.dll

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, dependencies, nuget, xunit.net

In a .NET project I am using XUnit to write and run my unit tests. Locally, everything works fine. But when I try to run the tests using Jenkins it fails.

The error message is:

```
Test:
  xUnit.net MSBuild runner (64-bit .NET 4.0.30319.1)
  xunit.dll:     Version 1.9.1.1600
  Test assembly: <http://…/Foo.Tests.dll>

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
assembly 'xunit.extensions, Version=1.6.1.1521, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c' or one of its dependencies. The located
assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

What's strange is that the requested version (1.6.1.1521) is nowhere used, neither in `app.config` nor in `packages.config` nor in the directly linked assemblies.

My guess is that something with NuGet (we use the `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` option) is wrong, but at least there is no obvious failure.

Any idea of what the problem might be, or how we could get a better feeling of where to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: the `app.config` file with the assembly binding redirects was in the wrong project …

Comment: Please elaborate a little on your answer..then mark it as "the answer", so it doesn't show up in the unanswered questions filter.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/daniel-chambers/xunit.ioc/issues/1) which appears to be the same issue OP here has - one has to "open the package manager console in VS and run Add-BindingRedirect against your test project" - I assume that's what this answer is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message.

Project A was referencing a different version of xunit than Project B and Project A was using an attribute from Project B.  Upgrading Project B's version of xunit resolved the issue.